# Accessing rows and columns in same dtype DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a bit surprised that for a unique dtype DataFrame (nxn dataFrame), it is slower to access a row than a column. From what I gather a DataFrame of identical dtype should be stored as a contiguous block in memory, so accessing rows or columns should be equally as fast (just a matter of updating the correct stride).

Sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 100))

%timeit df[0]
%timeit df.loc[0]
```

The slowest run took 12.86 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.72 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 116 µs per loop
```

There is definitely something I dont understand well about how a dataFrame is stored, thanks for your help !

Comment: I think the fairer comparison might be `df.loc[:, 0]` against `df.loc[0, :]`, though the former is still faster.

Comment: Can you please describe your question more clearly?

Comment: Sure: why is it faster to access a column than a row in same type dataFrame (with rows and columns of the same length) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the underlying `numpy` array, you'll see that access is the same speed for rows / columns, at least in my test:

```py
%timeit df.values[0]
# 10.2 µs ± 596 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit df.values[:, 0]
# 10.2 µs ± 730 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Series (columns) are more first-class citizens in a dataframe than rows are. I think accessing the columns is more like a dictionary lookup, which is why it's so fast. Usually there are few columns, and each is meaningful, so it makes sense to store them this way. There are often very many rows, though, and an individual row doesn't have as much significance. This is a bit of conjecture, though. You'd have to go look at the source code to see what is actually being called each time and determine from that why the operations take a different amount of time - maybe an answer will pop up with that later.

Here's another timing comparison:

```py
%timeit df.iloc[0, :]
# 141 µs ± 7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit df.iloc[:, 0]
# 61.9 µs ± 1.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Accessing the columns is quicker this way too, though much slower. I'm not sure what would explain this. I assume that the slowdown compared with accessing a row/column directly comes from needing to return a `pd.Series`. When accessing a row, a new `pd.Series` might need to be created. But I don't know why `iloc` is slower for columns too - perhaps it also creates a new series each time, since `iloc` can be used quite flexibly and might not return an existing series (or could return a dataframe). But if a new series is created both times, then I'm again at a loss for why one operation beats the other.

And for more completeness

```py
%timeit df.loc[0, :]
# 155 µs ± 6.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit df.loc[:, 0]
# 35.6 µs ± 1.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought (still think ?) that it would have been possible since all the data is contiguous to access data exactly like in a numpy array, hence same speed.

Comment: @MdM Recall, though, that you aren't getting a `numpy.ndarray` back, you're getting a `pandas.Series` So this is going to require at least a bit of extra time if a new series object has to be created, including determining what the index position is so you can assign it as the name of the series. Also, it makes sense that a method which is written to handle very general indexing (`.loc` or `.iloc`) is slower than `df[col_name]` which specializes in only one simple operation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in the implementation details of Pandas, but I've used it enough that I can make an educated guess.

As I understand it, the Pandas data structure is most directly comparable to a dictionary of dictionaries, where the first index is the columns. Thus, the DF:

```
   a b
 c 1 2
 d 3 4
```

is essentially `{'a': {'c': 1, 'd': 3}, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 4}}`. I'll assume I'm correct about that assertion from here on out, and would love to be corrected if someone knows more about pandas.

Thus, indexing a column is a simple hash lookup, whereas indexing a row requires iterating over all columns and doing a hash lookup for each one.

I think the reasoning is that this makes it really efficient to access a particular attribute of all rows and add new columns, which is normally how you interact with a dataframe. For such tabular use cases, it's much faster than a simple matrix layout, since you don't have to stride through memory (a whole column is stored more or less locally), but of course that's a tradeoff that makes interacting with rows less efficient (hence why it's not as easy syntactically to do so; you'll note that most Pandas operations default to interacting with columns, and interacting with rows is more or less a secondary objective in the module).

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you if we can assume the nested dict structure. But I thought that since it is stored by blocks of dtype, it was possible to skip this structure when all dtypes are the same.